# What is the plug model to match a bm04b gh connector

Tags: connector, plug

I'm building a MEMs project using the omron D6T-44L, and the connector on it is so tiny I cant even solder tap on to the back.
I've searched and am having no luck finding the name of the model that will fit in to the bm04b gh connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [datasheet](https://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pdf/en-d6t.pdf):

[image: Cable assembly, optional, for the D6T series from page 4 of https://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pdf/en-d6t.pdf]

The cable connector is `GHR-04V-S` and the internal contacts for the connector are `SSHL-002T-P0.2`.